# Visual Studio Git Changes loads ALL my computer files when starts

Tags: git

Visual Studio is trying to load all my files on the computer from some reason..
Please look here ->
[Git changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He9ID.png)

I cannot revert this for some reason. Visual studio freezez and i cannot work. I've reinstalled VS twice and still this happens.. PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Remove the .git folder from your profile folder.

Comment: I agree with @fredrik that you very likely can just delete the .git folder which probably ended up there accidentally. However, if you open a command prompt in that directory and type `git log`, you can at least see if there is any history there before you delete it.

Comment: Thank you! It stopped loading all the files. Do you have any idea how the heck that even happend?

Comment: One way is to type `git init` in a command prompt in that directory, but I'm guessing you didn't do that since you'd probably remember it. Maybe you clicked on "Add folder to source control" or "Create Git Repo" when you had that folder open in a tool that can do it, such as Visual Studio.